# how to play an audio playlist with the assets_audio_player flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been creating a player, I have used many packages but none have given me the result I want, I recently found the package assets_audio_player: but I could not find a way to reproduce a playList with this player, any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
assetsAudioPlayer.openPlaylist(Playlist(
      assetAudioPaths: [
        "assets/audio/test1.mp3",
        "assets/audio/test2.mp3",
      ],
    ));
```

> You can try this, It’s work for me.
>
> ```
> assetsAudioPlayer.playlistPlayAtIndex(index);
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> assetsAudioPlayer.playOrPause();
> ```

Comment: Could you please send me a short example where you show me how you implement it, I'm trying and it doesn't work for me

Comment: because I try to follow the code you sent me, however, the assetsAudioPlayer does not give me the option of openPlaylist, it only gives me the option of open

Comment: assets_audio_player: ^1.2.3

Comment: There's an issue on iOS